# Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to integer in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The compiler reports the line with the call to `Math.pow()` as an error. I'm making a program that computes the solution to a quadratic by using the quadratic formula with inputted variables for class. Arrow for convenience

```
import java.util.*;
public class QuadraticFormula {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter b: ");
        int b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter c: ");
        int c = input.nextInt();

    →   int discriminant = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);

        input.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this type mismatch has everything to do with java, and nothing to do with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it as an int:

```
int discriminant = (int)(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
```

This is because Math.pow() expects 2 doubles and returns a double.  So the Runtime will up-cast `b` and `2` from `int` to `double` then return a `double`.  Then it will up-cast `4`, `a`, and `c` to `double`s.  The result is a `double`.  It must be cast back down to `int`.  This is safe in this case because we know all input values are `int`s.